# Making a VHD image of a drive, using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vhd

I would like to make a VHD image of a harddisk.

I know how to make VHD images (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848503.aspx) but i would like the image to contain alle the content from an existing drive.

The solution im currently thinking about is making a VHD the same size as the source drive, and then copy all files over from the source drive, but i think there got to be a cleaner (easier) way.

I know about Drive2Vhd from Sysinternals, but i need to do this with PowerShell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about recreating the wheel? You can download and call that exe from the live.sysinternals.com site move the vhd around after your done creating it all with powershell.

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to avoid using Disk2vhd you can wrap two excellent exes inside of some powershell logic to get the job done.

To be more manual about how you create and load it with data you run the following commands that you wrapped inside of a powershell script.

#### Step 1 - Create the VHD in Diskpart

```
> diskpart
DISKPART> create vdisk file=”c:\test\test.vhd” maximum=1000
DISKPART> select vdisk file="c:\test\test.vhd"
DISKPART> attach vdisk
DISKPART> create partition primary
DISKPART> assign letter=X noerr
DISKPART> exit
```

#### Step 2 - Copy the files into your new vhd

```
Robocopy <Source> <Destination> *.* /S /MT:128
```

#### Step 3 - Detach the vhd

```
select vdisk file="c:\test\test.vhd"
detach vdisk
exit
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the options `/mir /zb /copyall` instead of `/s` for this kind of task.

Comment: Thank you @AnsgarWiechers I have updated my answer to reflect the correct tool name.